# I'm trying to show a div for 5 seconds before fade it out and remove it. How can I do that?

Tags: jquery

So.. I'm trying to call a function that shows a div and keep it visible for 5 seconds and then fades it out in a fast fadeOut (1 sec, for example).

The way I'm doing is not exactly what I expected... 
I did this:

```
function myFunc() {
     $( ".myDiv" ).show( "fast", function() {});
     $(".myDiv").fadeOut(5000, function() {
          $(this).remove();
     });    
}
```

But as result I get a div fade during 5 seconds.. And I want to show 5 seconds e fadeOut fast. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using jQuery [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
function myFunc() {
     $( ".myDiv" ).show( "fast").delay(5000).fadeOut('fast', function() {
          $(this).remove();
     });    
}
```

here is jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qwdv0bsu/1/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `show`, use `fadeIn` instead. And, the `fadeOut` should be inside the callback of `setTimeout` which triggeres it after 5 sec.

```js
$( ".myDiv" ).fadeIn("fast");

setTimeout(function(){ 
    $(".myDiv").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}, 5000);
```

```css
.myDiv{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/54Luggfp/1/)

Read up:

- [fadeIn | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)
- [fadeOut | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)
- [setTimeout() | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
setTimeout('myFunc',5000);
```

This will do **'myFunc()'** after 5 secs.

Answer (score 0):

draw you div normally then set a timer like the following:

```
setInterval(
    function () { 
     $(".myDiv").fadeOut(100, function() {
       $(this).remove();
    }); }, 
    5000
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you used remove() .. while fadeOut will display it to none

```
function myFunc() {
     $( ".myDiv" ).fadeIn(5000).delay(2000).fadeOut('fast');
}
```